# Oauth Implementation using PHP and JS facebook SDK

Tags: codeigniter, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Hai Fellow Developers,

I am implementing A facebook Login to my Web App using codeigniter (E-commerce kind of platform).

So, I have lot of filters in my site based upon them i am trying to fetch data and requesting a service. so user has to log in to request a service, so at last i am forcing user to login to continue (like buying something).

Here comes the problem, I implemented Facebook login using Javascript SDK and trying to get accesstoken. and created a FACEBOOK library in codeigniter which fetches user's data using [FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper/5.0.0). and now i should update user details in all sessions and attach the user name dynamically to the current view in codeigniter.

you can look below what i have tried upto now:

**Facebook Libabry:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
  session_start();
}

// Autoload the required files
require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/autoload.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

class Facebook {
  var $ci;
  var $helper;
  var $session;
  var $permissions;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->permissions = $this->ci->config->item('permissions', 'facebook');

    // Initialize the SDK
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $this->ci->config->item('api_id', 'facebook'), $this->ci->config->item('app_secret', 'facebook') );

      $this->helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
            // No session exists
      try {
          $this->session = $this->helper->getSession(); 
      } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {

      } catch( Exception $ex ) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues

      }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the login URL.
   */
  public function login_url() {
    return $this->helper->getLoginUrl( $this->permissions );
  }

  /**
   * Returns the current user's info as an array.
   */
  public function get_user() {

    if ( $this->session) {

      $request = ( new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me' ) )->execute();

      // Get response as an array
      $user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();

      return $user;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public function logout(){
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
  }

}
```

And in My controller i have my index function like this

```
public function index(){
    $fb_data = $this->facebook->get_user();
    $profile_data=array(
        'name'=>$fb_data['name'],
        'id' =>$fb_data['id'],
        'image'=>'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_data['id'].'/picture?width=300',
        'email'=>$fb_data['email'],
        'oauthProvider'=>'facebook',
        );
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_name', $fb_data['name']);
    echo json_encode($profile_data);
}
```

My Header View:

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('user_name')): ?>

            <li id="userName" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" id="userNameAnchor" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome <span class="user_name"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_name')?></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Account settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('redirectoauth/FbLogout')?>">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
<?php else: ?>
<li id="login"><a href="#socialLogin" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Ajax call

```
    $.ajax({ 
url:"<?php echo base_url('redirectoauth');?>", 
success:function(data){ 
var data=$.parseJSON(data); 
$('.user_name').html(data.name); 
$('#userName').css('display','block') 
$('#login').css('display','none'); 
$('#socialLogin').modal('hide'); 
} 
});
```

Any references or tuts,suggestions on architecture to overcome this problem.

Comment: are you not able to set session all our site for facebook login ?

Comment: @user1048123 not able to get you

Comment: what actually issue you are getting ? Are you not able to set session after facebook login ?

Comment: You know i am getting the data from facebook library to a controller but i can't able to update it in current view. i am able to set in session. since i am using JS SDK view is not redirecting here.

Comment: ok so you are able to set session in contoller using ajax and send  response to view right ? but in view you are not able to see session changes after response right ?

Comment: exactly, if u can see my controller from above it is setting session and echoing the response. but in view i have written like if session is set display username else display login.

Comment: can you share some code of view also ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83507/discussion-between-user1048123-and-saikiran).

Answer (score 0):

this will fix your issue

ajax call

```
$.ajax({ 
url:"<?php echo base_url('redirectoauth');?>", 
    success:function(data){ 
    var data=$.parseJSON(data); 
    $('.user_name').html(data.name); 
    $('#logined').css('display','block') 
    $('#sociallogined').css('display','none'); 
    $('#socialLogin').modal('hide'); 
} 
});
```

view

```
<ul id="logined" <?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_name') ? 'style="display:none"' :''; ?>>
    <li id="userName" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" id="userNameAnchor" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome <span class="user_name"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_name')?></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Account settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('redirectoauth/FbLogout')?>">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
<ul id="sociallogined">
    <li id="login"><a href="#socialLogin" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```